exam class fillin line spacing
How can I space the fillin section further apart? I feel like this is obvious but I'm missing it...
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

This preamble is not spaced further apart. This preamble is not spaced further apart. This preamble is not spaced further apart. 


\begin{questions}

\question[6] \setstretch{2} The \fillin[quick] brown fox jumped over the lazy \fillin[hare]. The \fillin[quick] brown fox jumped over the lazy \fillin[hare]. The \fillin[quick] brown fox jumped over the lazy \fillin[hare].

\question[1] This question is not spaced further apart. This question is not spaced further apart. This question is not spaced further apart. 

\end{questions}

\end{document}


You get “Undefined control sequence” for \setstretch, don't you?
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

This preamble is not spaced further apart.
This preamble is not spaced further apart.
This preamble is not spaced further apart.

\begin{questions}

\begin{spacing}{2}
\question[6] The \fillin[quick] brown
  fox jumped over the lazy \fillin[hare]. The \fillin[quick]
  brown fox jumped over the lazy \fillin[hare].
  The \fillin[quick] brown fox jumped over the lazy \fillin{here}.
\end{spacing}

\question[1] This question is not spaced further apart.
  This question is not spaced further apart.
  This question is not spaced further apart.

\end{questions}

\end{document}



Yes, I do; thanks this works great.

@alice19 So You can upvote and accept the answer!

I am grateful for the reminder.
